# Can Boolean FALSE and TRUE be redefined

Tags: php

I'm reading a book about PHP, and about using `TRUE` and `FALSE`, it says :

> In fact, the lowercase versions are more stable, because PHP does not
>   allow you to redefine them; the uppercase ones may be redefined

I tried to redefine `TRUE` and `FALSE`, and it didn't work!! I google redefining constants and found out that i need to use `runkit_constant_redefine()`, i don't have runkit extension installed so i can't try it on TRUE and FALSE..

My question is, Can `TRUE`, `true`, `FALSE` or `false` be redefined with or without `runkit_constant_redefine()` ?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to change the boolean values?! Can you not just define your own constants? `myTrue` and `myFalse`?

Comment: I hardly doubt that `TRUE` is something else than `true`, `True` or `tRue`. That's PHP - case doesn't matter… sometimes. It's cold outside, use that book to make some fire.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen  as i said "I'm reading a book" so i'm just learning and wondering :D i don't intend to redefine them anyway

Comment: @KarmenSali Okay. If I worked on a project and someone changed the booleans I would probably dedicate my life to reinstating the death penalty... ;)

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen https://github.com/kitcambridge/evil.js/blob/gh-pages/evil.js

Comment: See this snippet: https://3v4l.org/S2AFZ. Seems can't be done anymore in PHP 7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boolean true is defined as *case-insensitive* constant, with `true` being the default notation.

```
 define("true", 1, 1);
```

That means it will work in any other casing as well, be it `TRUE` or `True` or `TrUe` or `tRUE`.

What your book alludes to is redefining the constant in another case variant again. Which you can. All but the lowercase `true` are open spots in the constant lookup table.

With e.g. `define("True", 2)` it will take precedence over the lowercase-defined `true` which would substitute for the other cases else.

It's pointless advice from your book anyway. Even though you could declare a dozen variants for the boolean constants, nobody actually does that. The presumed "more stable" reasoning is practically bogus. Prefer the notation that's *more readable* or matches the existing coding style.

Comment: My php-5.6.0 doesn't redefine `True`. Which php did? Can you also provide a reference to "`true` being the default notation", please?

Comment: Works in the CLI runtime of all variants (tested with 4.4.7, 5.0, 5.1). There are semantic inconsisties around PHP 5.2 though. Starting from PHP 5.3 you'd need a `namespace` declared to observe it (works in 5.4, 5.5, 5.6). See https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_constants.c, notice the uppercase `REGISTER_MAIN_BOOL_CONSTANT("TRUE",` but also CONST_CS actually lowercasing it again in `zend_register_constant`.

Comment: I see, it's an implementation detail. Redefining `True` is obviously a pre-namespace feature. Defining `True` within a namespace is a different thing, as you are defining `mynamespace\True` which is something else then `\True`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define different `true` and `false` in every namespace.

```
namespace foo;

define('foo\true', 0);
if (true) {
    echo 'This will be never printed.';
}
```

Comment: This does get printed, at least in PHP 8.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, for the uppercase versions:

```
$ php
php > var_dump(defined('TRUE'), TRUE);
bool(true)
bool(true)
php > define('TRUE', 'arglebargle');
php > var_dump(defined('TRUE'), TRUE);
bool(true)
string(11) "arglebargle"

php > echo phpversion();
5.4.16
```

Lowercase, not so much:

```
php > var_dump(defined('true'), true);
bool(true)
bool(true)
php > define('true', 'foobarbaz');
PHP Notice:  Constant true already defined in php shell code on line 1
```

But why would you want to? Redefining reality rarely works out in the end.

Comment: Different output here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/vPe1r2 (tested all available PHP versions, not only 5.6.0)

Answer (score -1):

Here's an excerpt from PHP's manual [Booleans](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php):

> the constants TRUE or FALSE. Both are case-insensitive.
>
> …
>
> ```
> $foo = True; // assign the value TRUE to $foo
> ```
>
> …
>
> ```
> if ($show_separators == TRUE) {
> ```

As this is the wording of the manual you can assume that new releases likely won't break backward compatibility. You can consider writing `True` in any case stable. Although using one consistent code style is recommended. But this has nothing to do with stability.

<sub>The fact that the case-insensitive constant is stored with the canonicalized lower case `true` is an implementation detail and has no further relevance.</sub>

---

Regarding those who claim to redefine `TRUE`: The only scenario I managed to do that was in an own namespace:

```
namespace foo;

define("TRUE", "bar");
assert (TRUE === "bar");
assert (TRUE !== \TRUE)
```

This is defining `foo\TRUE`, not `\TRUE`!

Mario wrote, in pre-namespace PHP versions (PHP<5.3) redefining `TRUE` was possible. Well, PHP-5.3 was released 5 years ago. Surprisingly the [market share of PHP<5.3](http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/pl-php/5/all) is around 23% (of PHP-5). So I guess there is still valid relevance for this topic.