# Why TRUE and FALSE can be re-defined?

Tags: php

While reading a book I got this note:

> Note that I am using uppercase letters for the names TRUE and FALSE.
>   This is because they are predefined constants in PHP. You can also
>   use the lowercase versions, if you prefer, as they are also predefined.
>   In fact, the lowercase versions are more stable, because PHP does not
>   allow you to redefine them; the uppercase ones may be redefined—
>   something you should bear in mind if you import third-party code.

But earlier I noticed that php constants cannot be re-defined. So, why TRUE and FALSE can be re-defined?

Comment: Asked, answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26532998/can-boolean-false-and-true-be-redefined

Comment: Thanks for the link. But the link questions about can it be re-defined? But I am asking why it can be re-defined?

Comment: Ultimately, "why" is an open-ended and off-topic question here. That said, the answer on that post provides an explanation in the technical sense. It's because PHP says so. The constants lookup table only reserves the lowercase forms, `true` and `false`, meaning you can override the default behavior (case-insensetivity) with your own constants. As for why PHP says so, that's a different question likely unable to be answered here.

Comment: Technically, I hope to get a perfect answer over here in StackOverflow.

Comment: I suspect this is really off-topic for SO, unfortunately. Generally open-ended questions that likely lacks an objective answer are not appropriate.

Comment: Something about rolling and squares...